# Image view adding vertical spaces to the images on Android

Tags: java, android

How to scale the image in Image view? currently i follow the other suggestions given in this thread to set the image in Imageview, but it is adding vertical spaces to the image set in a form menu item. i want to see only the height of the image in the menu item. Can anybody help me in this issue?

Note: iam adding image to the view dynamically and it will not present in the package resource folder.

Answer (score 0):

In general if you want to scale an image, you convert it to a `Bitmap` first (if it's a resource), and use the static method `createScaledBitmap()` of the Bitmap class.

Ex:

```
Bitmap originalBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.my_image);
Bitmap scaledBitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalBitmap, newWidth, newHeight, false);

imageView.setImageBitmap(scaledBitmap);
```

Comment: I cannot set width and height of the image to display bcoz it should run on different screen sizes starting from 3.0 inch to internet tablets screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

and maybe use a different ScaleType...

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with vertical spaces?is it padding?
if yes you can set it with view.setpadding(int left,int top,int right,int bottom)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPadding(int, int, int, int)

Comment: i am setting a bigger image than screen size. It is adjusting the horizontal size of the image to fit the screen but not vertical size.I see some large white space on either side of the vertical edges of the image in view which results me to scroll down to see the image.